# Fill NAN values during Pandas merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, merge

I have a little problem but I don't find solutions...I want to merge two dataframes and I want to fill in the NaN values using the information from each dataframes...
Consider two dataframes :

- First people :

| id | skills | diploma |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | nan | omicron |
| 2 | beta | nan |
| 5 | beta | epsilon |
| 6 | omega | zeta |

- and jobs :

| id | people_id | skills | diploma |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | alpha | nan |
| 20 | 2 | nan | zeta |
| 30 | 3 | beta | pi |
| 40 | 4 | omega | zeta |

When I use Pandas merge :

```py
pd.merge(people, jobs, left_on='id', right_on='people_id', how='inner')
```

and I have this result :

| id_x | skills_x | diploma_x | id_y | people_id | skills_y | diploma_y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | nan | omicron | 10 | 1 | alpha | nan |
| 2 | beta | nan | 20 | 2 | nan | zeta |

I want to produce via Pandas merge a new dataframe where each line is a job and i want to
fill NaN value, keep the job's id (because each line is a job) and keep one time the columns "skills" and "diploma", like this :

| id | people_id | skills | diploma |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | alpha | omicron |
| 20 | 2 | beta | zeta |

To code to reproduce :

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

people = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,5,6], 'skills': [np.nan, "beta", "beta", "omega"], 'diploma': ["omicron", np.nan, "epsilon", "zeta"]})
jobs = pd.DataFrame({'id':[10,20,30,40], 'people_id':[1,2,3,4], 'skills': ["alpha", np.nan, "beta", "omega"], 'diploma': [np.nan, "zeta", "pi", "zeta"]})
```

Answer (score 1):

The combine_first method is the one you are looking for friend

```
filled_people = people.combine_first(jobs)
```

Just be carefull with your indexes and make sure they match, like column A to be filled has the same name in your jobs df.

Comment: Fine. Never seen the `combine_first` pandas method. 
Just one thing: I think that you probably have to "clean" the columns not needed.

Answer (score 1):

First merge the dataframe:

```
merged_df = pd.merge(
    people.rename(columns={"id":"people_id"}), #renaming the id of people table
    jobs,
    on='people_id', how='inner', suffixes=[".people", ".jobs"]
).set_index(["people_id","id"])

#creating the second columns level
merged_df.columns = merged_df.columns.str.split(".", expand=True)
```

Now `merged_df` is:

```
                skills  diploma skills  diploma
                people  people  jobs    jobs
people_id   id              
1           10  NaN     omicron alpha   NaN
2           20  beta    NaN     NaN     zeta
```

Then your task can be solved by the following lines:

```
merged_df["skills"] = merged_df["skills"].apply(lambda x: pd.Series.dropna(x)[0], axis=1)
merged_df["diploma"] = merged_df["diploma"].apply(lambda x: pd.Series.dropna(x)[0], axis=1)

#remove the second level (we don't need it anymore)
merged_df.columns = merged_df.columns.droplevel(1)

#remove duplicate columns
merged_df = merged_df.loc[:,merged_df.columns.duplicated()]
```

Finally `merged_df` is:

```
                skills  diploma
people_id   id
1           10  alpha   omicron
2           20  beta    zeta
```

If you prefer you can `reset_index()`.

PS: Note that if `skills` or `diploma` have `NaN` value in both dataframes for a person, then the algorithm will rise an error.

Comment: Nice approach, my dude. very cool way of thinking without being too much method based. Just a litle piece of improvement. You can just grab your merged_df at once, and apply only one time no need to do it twice. Apply interacts through each element of your df.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure that a faster method exists lol.